# Need to find the version of installed apk on my android device

Tags: bash

I have an apk installed on the device and I want to know the version of the installed apk. I had tried with `pm list packages` but it wasn't listing the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right you could use `dumpsys` and `grep versionName`
Use this command 
`adb -s <device_serial_no> shell dumpsys package <package_name> | grep versionName`

NOTE:  is the one which begins with `com.`

example : `com.king.candysrushsaga`

Comment: It worked thanks. But Isn't it supposed to be com.king.candycrushsaga and not srushsaga... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use AAPT from your path/to/android-sdk/build-tools/your-api-version-available/...

```
aapt dump badging app.apk
```

this should output:

```
package: name='com.info.app' versionCode='xxxx' versionName='x.x.x'
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot this works too. I just wish there could be more than 1 accepted answers :(